# how to use an Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
    List<MyObjectOne> myListOne = new List<MyObjectOne>(){new MyObjectOne { ID = 1, field2 = 2}};

    List<MyObjectTwo> myListTwo = new List<MyObjectTwo>(){new MyObjectTwo { ID = 4, field6 = "string"}};

    bool hasSomething = false;
    var result = new[] { new {ID = 0 }}.ToList();

    if (hasSomething)
    {
        // Use list one.
         result = myListOne.Select(x => new { ID =  x.ID});
    }
    else
    {
        // Use list two.
        result = myListTwo.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID });
    }

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        // Some logic to manipulate item.ID.
        item.ID;
    }
```

What I trying to do it's to use the same anonymous type to select a list of IDs from two different lists. So I use the `Select(x => new { ID = x.ID })` in order to create the anonymous type for each table **in order to have only one for loop.**

The error raised is "*Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable to List*"

¿any idea?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ID` in `MyObjectOne` and `MyObjectTwo` are both `int`'s, your code will work if you replace [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var result = new[] { new { ID = 0 } }.AsEnumerable();
```

If the `ID` properties are some other type (e.g. `long`'s), you need to specify that when creating the anonymous type here:

```
var result = new[] { new { ID = 0L } }.AsEnumerable();
```

Or like this:

```
var result = new[] { new { ID = (long)0 } }.AsEnumerable();
```

However, this kind of code is kind of confusing, and I wouldn't recommend it for a production environment. Here's an alternative solution that avoids creating a 'dummy' object just for implicit anonymous typing:

```
var result = hasSomething 
    ? myListOne.Select(x => new { ID =  x.ID })
    : myListTwo.Select(x => new { ID =  x.ID });
```

Comment: If I use var `result = new[] { new { ID = 0 } }.AsEnumerable();` the error raised is: "_Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> to 
IEnumerable<AnonymousType#2>_". 
But the alternative solution is just perfect :)

Comment: @Coyolero It shouldn't throw that error if the `ID` properties in both classes are `int`'s. What type are they?

Comment: @Coyolero Strange. I tested it with `int`'s and it works fine; it only throws that exception when the properties are a `long`, `uint`, etc. (but even if that's the case the fix is pretty easy).

Comment: sorry, I just checked the code again and the `ID` properties are `long`'s. If I change them to `int`'s it works. As I said, I would use the alternative solution, but, what would be the fix?

Comment: @Coyolero See my updated answer for how you can use the first solution with `long`'s.